# What are the good sample projects in github which used tess-two repository?

Tags: android, github, ocr

What are the good sample projects in github which used [tess-two](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two) repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**android ocr**](https://github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr) - [an intermediate project]

[**Simple-Android-OCR**](https://github.com/GautamGupta/Simple-Android-OCR) - [a simple project]